# Do different disks have different system restore points?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, hard-drive, cleaning, system-restore

I was wondering if I install programs in both `C:\` drive and `D:\` drive, are there separate system restore points for each disk?

For example if I run `cleanmgr.exe` I can select either C:\ or D:\ drive:

[image]

Beyond that, I have two different screens which allow me to clean up system restore and shadow copies.

One for `C:\`:

[image]

and one for`D:\`:

[image]

Is it true that one is cleaning up the shadow copies of `C:` while the other is cleaning up the shadow copies of `D:`,

Or is it true that they are pointing to the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadow Copies are specific to the volume they were created on, if created manually. When used as a System Restore backend, though, all copies created at the same time are tied to a single "restore point" and are removed together.

Comment: If I did a manual system restore on `C:`, then do a manual system restore on `D:`, then delete "all but the last" system restore (as in the last screenshot above). Are the system restores on `C:\` gone ?

Comment: @Pacerier: The system restore on D isn't a system restore, but a backup of only files changed on D.

Comment: @surfasb ic, so the concept of system restore is only available for drives that hold the `Windows` directory?

Comment: @Pacerier: The other drives merely get "regular" backups.